# windows 10 Home errors with vb6 inet control on networked drive

Tags: windows-10, internet, vb6

Got a utility program I wrote many years ago in vb6 that uses the vb6 inet control to access a website to update itself.  The update feature works fine on hundreds of machines running XP, win7, win8, win10, svr 2003, and others, installed on local and networked drives.

There is however one new win 10 home machine where it does not work (the update, the program itself works fine) if the program in run from a networked drive.  If run it from the c: drive it works, if copied to the networked f: drive I get the error 'Name not resolved', referring to the update site url.

I turned off the MacAfee firewall with no effect.  The program is digitally signed so it should be trusted.  The url is working, and can be navigated to from IE and Chrome on the machine.

The program was originally installed on the c: drive but an identical copy resides on the f: drive, and the program runs fine on the networked drive it just can't connect to the update site.

Is this a security feature, if so how do I disable it, or is this a limitation of  win 10 home (as opposed to professional).

I know home has some limitations, like it does not support remote desktop (which is stupid IMO).

How can I trouble shoot this problem?

MORE INFO:

So I uninstalled the program from c: with the intention of re-installing on networked f: to see it that has some effect.  However, in the wise installer I cannot select a networked drive for installaion...only c: and cdrom d: are listed.  Why can't it see the mapped drive letters?

MORE:

After reboot wise installer can see networked drives.  Installing on network does not fix the problem.  In addition to the vb6 inet control, API calls to wininet fail from exe on network but succeed from exe on local c: drive.

SIMPLE PROBLEM RESTATEMENT:

some.exe (32-bit) uses wininet.dll to connect to internet to post some data to http://myurl.com. some.exe is installed at c:\path\some.exe and also on a network share f:\path\some.exe.

from cmd prompt:

c:\path> some.exe (works)

c:\path> f:\path\some.exe (fails with error 12007 name not resolved)

f:\path> some.exe  (fails with error 12007 name not resolved)

f:\path> c:\path\some.exe  (works)

conclusion: if some.exe resides on a network share internet access is blocked.

McAfee is uninstalled. Firewall is off. Internet security zones set to minimum. target url added as a trusted site.

Comment: BTW, although MS has abridged Windows 10 Home, Remote Desktop *can* be installed: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-rdpwrapper-win10-home Of course, Windows Update may remove any modifications. sigh

Comment: Does the program on the network drive run with elevated privileges (admin)?

Comment: What happens if you try to ping the URL with a command prompt from the networked drive on that Win 10 machine?  Is is also not able to resolve the name?

Comment: Elevated permissions does not help.  No suspect entries in event viewer.

Comment: ping from cmd prompt works fine.

Comment: Is the share on a server that is using SMB 1.0?

Comment: It is server 2003, so yes it uses SMB 1x.  Should be noted I can access the network and mapped drives.  After a reboot the wise installer can see the mapped drives.  Installing on network did not fix the problem.

Comment: This is starting to look like an IE security zone problem...

Comment: Windows 10 and SMBv1.  SMBv1 is disabled on Windows 10 by default.

Comment: Checked, SMB 1.0 in on.

Comment: Honestly, I thought I would discover this was common knowledge to everyone but me.  That network residing exe's can't access the internet seems like a reasonable security precaution (for a home o/s) but I can find no info on this. Strange.

Comment: Must be >= SMB 2.0 according to this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6e02671c-fd50-4bcc-a41b-d8ff7d835ce6/apps-that-run-on-network-drives-cant-access-internet?forum=win10itpronetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that windows 10 version 1803 update (Windows 10 April 2018 Update) blocks internet access for programs hosted on network drives using SMB1x.  SMB version must be 2.0 or greater. SMB 2.0 was introduced in Server 2008. Thanks to EBGreen for the SMB lead.

EDIT: RESOLUTION

June 26, 2018 KB4284848 Applies to: Windows 10, version 1803 fixes this issue.